# Proof that the set is countable - my idea

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The set:$S:=\{T\subset\ \Bbb N: T$ is finite or $\Bbb N \backslash T$ is finite$\}$

Since all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ are countable, can i just prove that since $\Bbb N \backslash T$ would simply be $\{t; t \in \Bbb N$ $t \notin T\}$...All though i do have the question how could $\Bbb N \backslash T$ be a finite set???

Comment: You mean "the set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is countable", otherwise you're stating a triviality. There are exactly as many finite sets as sets with finite complement.

Comment: The right part of the clause is obviously relevant if $T$ is infinite.

Comment: In fact, you didn't state a theorem. What is there to prove ??

Comment: Any part of a countable set is countable: you can enumerate the naturals and skip the missing elements.

Comment: Oh yeah I made a mistake let me redo it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$F = \{T \subset \mathbb{N}: T\text{ is finite} \} $$

$$I = \{T \subset \mathbb{N}: \mathbb{N}\setminus T \text{ is finite} \}$$

$$= \{\mathbb{N}\setminus T : T \in F \}$$

Thus there is a bijection $\phi : I \rightarrow F$ where one has
$$\phi(A) = \mathbb{N}\setminus A$$

Now suppose we are given a bijection $\rho: F \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

Consider the map $\beta : S \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined via

$$\beta(s) = 2 \rho(s)\text{ if }s \in F$$
$$= 2\rho(\phi(s))-1\text{ if }s \in I$$

note that this is a bijection.

Comment: I'm sorry could you clarify that a bit more....i am a bit lost at where you say consider the map $\beta (s)=2p(s)$ why does 2 p come from and why 2p?

Comment: $2p$ is basically the map that multiples the output of $p$ by $2$.

Comment: Yeah I realized that but why thou:)? I mean why use 2p...

Comment: Because this way you have outputs in the even and odd numbers and thus $S$ is mapped bijectively with $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Aha got it ... Thanks I'll think it over again!

Comment: sorry if you can quickly explain something would be great: I'm not quite clear on the difference of the set $F$ and the set $I$. F requires T to be a finite set and I requires that basically (N-T) to be a finite set. But the definition of N is it is a countably infinite set. So N-T would also be infinite.....So I am not quite sure of the difference between the two sets....

Comment: For each $T$ which is finite $\mathbb{N}\setminus T$ is infinite, but it is one object when viewed as a collection. $I$ is a countably infinite set that contains objects which hold countably infinite natural numbers.

Comment: Does that mean for the definition of the set S we can leave out the part "The set::={⊂ ℕ: is finite or ℕ∖ is finite}" where it says "r ℕ∖ is finite" since it is always infinite?

Comment: $S = \{T\subseteq \mathbb{N}:\text{  }T\text{ is finite}\}\cup\{J \subseteq \mathbb{N}: \text{ }\mathbb{N}\setminus J\text{ is finite} \}$

Comment: ....still not quite sure I got it....no difference seems like

Comment: What didn't you get?

Comment: The set T is the same set as the set J ? From your last comment? I mean the set of natural numbers minus any set is still infinite. So that definition is meaningless

Comment: Oh...maybe you don't know some commonly used notation...I will write it in full form; – 
$F = \{ \text{Finite subsets of } \mathbb{N}\}$, this set is countable.  $I = \{ \text{Infinite subsets of }\mathbb{N}\text{ such that the complement of any element inside this set is a finite set in }\mathbb{N} \}$; this set is a countable set. $S = F\cup I$ the union of two countable sets; thus $S$ is countable.

Comment: Can you check if I understood it correctly : F consists of finite subsets of N and we call them T. And I consist of subsets within ....I still don't get the definition for I ...lol.....if T consists of all finite subsets of N already, how can N\T be any subset that's not already in T ??? And since they use the same letter to represent the T, shouldn't the two sets be the same set??

Comment: An element of $F$ is like for example $\{ 1,2,3\}$. An element of $I$ is for example $\{4,5,6,... \}$. The two sets F and I intersect nowhere.

Comment: So F+I would be countable subsets of N?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $:$ Let $X_n$ be the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ of cardinality $n.$ Then $|X_n| \leq |\mathbb N^n| = |\mathbb N|.$ Let $F$ be the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb N.$ Then $F = \bigcup\limits_{n \geq 0} X_n.$ Can you now finish?

Comment: Hi yeah this was my original idea but I wasn't sure if I could use this to prove it...and I want to use my own proof to solve it, and this proof was in my text book